# store a variable in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was trying to create `variables` in my bash shell which I could use whenever I wanted. More specifically, I wanted to create a variable which could store the path to a folder, example:

```
mypath = `pwd`
```

However, I can't do the following:

> cd $mypath

How can I resolve this? Also, I want to store this variable so I can use after I restart my system. Do I store this in the `.bashrc` file?

Comment: Read the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use spaces in assignment, ie

```
mypath=`pwd`
```

Comment: I just tried the code `cd $mypath`, but I still get an error: No such file or directory. I echoed to see the value and it has the right path.

Comment: You need to specify what error you get.

Comment: @JamesHallen, `cd "$mypath"`, not `cd $mypath`, if you want to ensure that it uses the path exactly as written. Otherwise it's string-split and glob-expanded.

Comment: `$ echo $cmepath 
/home/ish/Documents/Summer Internship/Programs` and error: `cd $cmepath
bash: cd: /home/ish/Documents/Summer: No such file or directory`

Comment: @JamesHallen Double quote all your expansions, always.

Comment: and if I want to re-use this variable, I store it in `.bashrc`?

Comment: @JamesHallen Depends. If you want it to be a shell variable, not exported to your environment, `.bashrc`. If you want it in your environment, set _and export_ it in `.bash_profile` -- in the latter case it's only set once, when you first log in, not every time a new shell is created... but because it's exported, that once is all you need.

Comment: I can't find a `.bash_profile` file, do I have to create one?

Answer (score 0):

Furthermore, if you want your variables to be globally available you can use the `export` command. Example: `export mypath="pwd"`.

If you want the variables to persist after reboot, then you do need to add it to `~/.bashrc`.

You can do this with `nano ~/.bashrc` and adding `export mypath="pwd"` to the end of the file